# Dependabot issue - cannot update glob-parent to a non-vulnerable version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, dependencies, dependabot

I've just started to use Dependabot and encountered an issue with one of its alerts. I was looking for an answer how to handle such vulnerabilities, but didn't fine any proper resource. What I can see that it is a dependency of my deps, so it affects package-lock file.

Here is what Dependabot provided:

```
Dependabot cannot update glob-parent to a non-vulnerable version
The latest possible version that can be installed is 3.1.0 because of the following conflicting dependencies:

eslint@8.8.0 requires glob-parent@^6.0.1
postcss-mixins@6.2.3 requires glob-parent@^3.1.0 via a transitive dependency on fast-glob@2.2.7
The earliest fixed version is 5.1.2.
```

I don't have `glob-parent` in my `package.json` file - it is just the dependency of my other dependencies. What is the attitude to handle such alerts? Should I `dismiss` it? As far as I know manually changing package-lock is not the way to go.